# Calling the browser from the command line with PHP?

Tags: php, browser, console

We have a PHP script that runs for a very long time (over 1 hour with XML) from the command prompt (terminal) in Windows7. That is all working fine, we set the path of PHP and run the script.

What we would like to do, is when it finishes, output some pages of data at the end via the web browser (Internet Explorer).

I'm not sure how to do this as I have never launched anything else from PHP and passed it values.

Do I use something like exec() or passthru()?

Comment: what do you mean "output some pages of data"? And, why do you need to do that through a browser as opposed to, say, sending an email?

Comment: The "data" is been saved in a CSV file. But I would actually like to visually see the results as well. Si I have some HTML/Bootstrap set up at the end. But because its running at the command prompt, it comes out in the command prompt. I would like at the end to call the browser (open Internet Explorer) and then show the HTML in it.

Comment: So yea, just use exec to open the browser and pass the page's url as a parameter (all in 1 string on the php side). Just try it out on a test page that only calls the exec command and you'll  see

Comment: Thats the part I'm getting stuck on at the moment Terminus. I use exec() he browser opens to the home page, when i close the browser it runs the html in the command prompt again. Just not sure how to pass the information I have $browser=exec('C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe'); as code. Should I be sending my "http://localhost" in the exec() command as well?

Comment: `$string = "pathToExe.exe http://path/to/site.php"` pass $string to exec

Comment: `$launchBrowser="C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe http://localhost//XML_reader//test.php";
$browser=exec($launchBrowser);`     I get an error saying 'C:\Program is not recognizd. I've screwed something up and can't see it.

Comment: Make your php string use single quotes and then wrap the exec path in double quotes. `'"C:\..." path/to/php'`

Comment: Thanks Terminus ! It works. It keeps trying to open multiple browser IE windows, but I should be able to work that out.

Comment: No worries. Good luck. Post the final solution to help others :)